# Update attachment file in SharePoint using custom JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, jquery-ajax

Anybody know how to update attachment file in list item using javascript? Any idea are so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found similar thread [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203511/update-attachment-of-list-item-using-rest-api-is-failing/215725).
According to the answer upvoted, unfortunately there is no API to overwrite the list attachment. So you need to check if the attachment is present or not and delete the attachment if already exists when attaching new attachment to list item.
Try code given in the link above.